# API Key Convention

Tags: api, api-key

Are all API keys hexadecimal numbers by some sort of unwritten convention?

Comment: API keys can be whatever you want them to be, obviously. If I needed to generate some, I 'd have a look at generating GUIDs because I know that what I want is unique identifiers and the wheel has already be invented. Then my keys would be hexadecimal numbers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Doing a md5 hash on a some semi random data (e.g. timestamp + userid + key) is a fast way to generate a key of a fixed length that is hard to guess.

Since md5 produces hex output, people just use it straight.  They could convert to a high base, but there is not generally a big push to do so since the difference in data transmitted is so small.

Answer (score 0):

No, API keys are hexadecimal numbers based upon a written convention.

API keys are based upon [UUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID).

"UUIDs are documented as part of ISO/IEC 11578:1996 "Information technology – Open Systems Interconnection – Remote Procedure Call (RPC)" and more recently in ITU-T Rec. X.667 | ISO/IEC 9834-8:2005. The IETF has published Standards Track RFC 4122 that is technically equivalent with ITU-T Rec. X.667 | ISO/IEC 9834-8."

MD5 keys used for most APIs are a version of UUIDs.